# SQL-Server: sp_spaceused gives zero rows but big dataSize for cleaned table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, disk-space

After cleaning my table with `DELETE FROM MyTable` (and executing `DBCC shrinkdatabase('MyDB')` should that matter) I run the statement `EXEC sp_spaceused MyTable`. The results confuse me:

```
tableName   numberOfRows   reservedSize   dataSize   indexSize   unusedSize
---------   ------------   ------------   --------   ---------   ----------
MyTable     0              21664 KB       20672 KB   736 KB      256 KB
```

As you can see there are zero rows, yet there's almost 21 MB of data. My question is: what are possible causes for this situation and/or how can I further investigate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DELETE does not reclaim space, it deletes rows.

Space can remain allocated for several reasons, 3 of which are:

- [ghost clean up](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/inside-the-storage-engine-ghost-cleanup-in-depth.aspx) is still running
- the table has no clustered index
- the system tables are not updated yet

Try

- `EXEC sp_spaceused 'MyTable', 'true'` to force a space used update
- `TRUNCATE  TABLE` which deallocates space, rather then deleting rows
- `DELETE  myTABLE WITH (TABLOCKX)` if no clustered index and can't use TRUNCATE

Don't run `DBCC shrinkdatabase` because it adds no value and it will simply grow again

Comment: Your first suggestion was half the solution, size is now down from 21MB to 13MB. As to the other suggestions: the table has a clustered index on the PK, and Truncate unfortunately couldn't help as the table is referenced by a FK. I'll have a look at the ghost clean up as well.

Comment: The other 13 MB is now gone, I'm guessing the ghost clean up bit was my missing piece.